# Empty Sealed Coke Cans

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Have an entire six pack of 1994 NY Rangers Stanely Cup Coke cans I saved as a souvenir. All cans are still sealed. Very little soda remains in bottom of cans. My best friend has same experience with his. Still sealed. No sings of sap, stickiness, or any other signs of leakage. Where did the soda go?

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/532731/how-is-a-25-year-old-can-of-soda-now-empty-without-having-been-opened-or-poked, which was closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be that [corrosion](https://fractory.com/aluminium-corrosion/) has created [pinholes](https://www.alumhm.com/a/how-to-prevent-pinholes-in-aluminum-foils.html).

A second guess would be that pinholes are the result of manufacturing defects.

Either way, pinholes allow water to evaporate over the decades.